# How to supress naive datetime warning in django

Tags: python, django, datetime

In django whenever i use Datetime.datetime.now() a runtime warning :
`enter code here received a naive datetime (2024-03-28 16:18:54.096253) while time zone support is active` is displayed , i want to supress this warning or basically tell django to ignore this warning, is there a change i can make in the settings file to tell django to ignore the naive datetime field warning
eg:

```
b = User.objects.create()
b.start = datetime.datetime.now()
b.save()
```

runtime warning : `received a naive datetime (2024-03-28 16:18:54.096253) while time zone support is active`
tried : setting `USE_TZ = False` in settings.py

Answer (score -1):

Try using `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`.

Also you can use  `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)` which is more correct in Python 3.x